# Does Bearer token have a fixed length?

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm implementing my authentication stack on net core 2.1
I', trying to generare a correct token and I haven't found any rule to follow to build it...starting from the length!
Some tips?

Comment: [Bearer tokens](https://oauth.net/2/bearer-tokens/): "A Bearer Token is an opaque string, not intended to have any meaning to clients using it. *Some* servers will issue tokens that are a short string of hexadecimal characters, while *others* may... " (My *emphasis*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is no. The length depends on the information it contains.